# Can a path colored by a greedy algorithm ever have more than 2 colors?

Tags: graph-theory

can a **path** with at least 3 vertices, colored by a greedy coloring algorithm, **not** have exactly 2 colors?

I believe that the answer is no, but I am not sure if I fully understand greedy coloring. If the answer is yes, can you provide an example?

also would it make a difference if a graph is labeled vs unlabeled?
If it does make it difference, can you answer the question for both labeled and unlabeled?

**note:** only concerned about undirected graphs

Answer (score 5):

Here is one way that a greedy coloring of a path may end up using more than $2$ colors.

Take a path on $4$ vertices:

```
1 --- 2 --- 3 --- 4
```

Suppose your greedy algorithm considers them in the order `1`, `4`, `2`, `3`.

When looking at vertex `1`, there are no already-colored neighbors to watch out for, so the algorithm will give vertex `1` the first available color: say, `RED`.

```
RED --- 2 --- 3 --- 4
```

When looking at vertex `4`, there are also no already-colored neighbors to watch out for, so the algorithm will color vertex `4` the same color `RED` for the same reason.

```
RED --- 2 --- 3 --- RED
```

When looking at vertex `2`, there is already a `RED` neighbor, so the greedy algorithm will use the next color on the list: say, `BLUE`.

```
RED --- BLUE --- 3 --- RED
```

Finally, when looking at vertex `3`, there are already both `RED` and `BLUE` neighbors, so the greedy algorithm will be forced to use a third color: say, `GREEN`.

```
RED --- BLUE --- GREEN --- RED.
```

There we have it.

Finally, note that this is as bad as it gets: with any vertex ordering of any path, each vertex will have at most $2$ previously-colored neighbors, eliminating at most $2$ colors, so you'll never end up with more than $3$ colors.